# HTML Good or Bad Practice to Uniquely Identified Elements

Tags: html

I am wondering if I have a table of whose size and content I dont know, and I want to manipulate its data, is it bad practice to add unique id's to each element?

For example lets say the table is representing information from a database.
Is it bad practice to have

```
<li id= ${database_element.id}>
```

A better example using this for loop, this displays a list of elements from a table in a database named files

```
<g:each in="${files}" var="d">
        <a id = "${d.unique_id}" class = "file" href="somelink.com" ><image id = "iconImage"  src="img/iconImage"/>
        </a>
</g:each>
```

So now each element of the table has its unique id from the database.

Is this a good or bad idea, especially when it comes to file storage i.e file/folder ids?

The reason I am asking is I cant see any other way of manipulating individual elements of the table without this?

Comment: It's good practice if you're going to be using more than one table, I would use a class instead of an ID though.

Comment: @Leonzola is there a reason to use class over idea thanks

Comment: Each page can have only one element with an ID

Comment: But each id is unique? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually fine.

There would really need to be some good reason for it to be bad.  I'll start a list of things...everybody feel free to add to this list...

1. There are weird characters in your database IDs and they didn't get converted well or HTML escaped properly.
2. The same thing as above, but going the other direction (from HTML ids to database IDs).
3. Your database IDs change for some odd reason, and then you send data back to the database using the old ID.
4. You pollute your ID namespace with these IDs, and then can't use numbers for other IDs (this could be solved by adding some prefix to your database ids, such as `db-`).

It really depends on your specific situation and I would just wait until you actually run into a problem before worrying about it.

Comment: So for security purposes, an id shouldn't be too much of a cause for worry? Is it possible to associate and id to a element without having it visible to anyone who views-page-source

Comment: @hat_to_the_back I don't know, I am not an expert in database security.

Comment: No it's not, if you set an id attribute in HTML it would show up, but if the system is build safely there isn't much one can do with the id of a record. If they can then the security issues are somewhere else.